# Using cases to determine which table should join

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have four tables `products`, `product_histories`, `vendor_invoices` and `invoices`

This is the query I have developed

```
SELECT p.product_id, product_name, vendor_name FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN product_histories AS ph ON p.product_id = ph.product_id
CASE
    WHEN ph.history_type = "P" THEN
        LEFT JOIN vendor_invoices AS vi ON link_id = vi.vi_id

    WHEN ph.history_type = "S" THEN
        LEFT JOIN invoices AS i ON i.invoice_id = link_id
END
ORDER BY ph_id ASC
```

What I want that if `ph.history_type` is `P` then is should join `vendor_invoices` and if it is `S` then it should join `invoices`. But it says there is a syntax error.
Can anyone help me out with it? Or could show a better way to achieve this problem.

Comment: this smells like a table design flaw. Why are all invoices not in the same table, with a column value to indicate if it's a vendor invoice or not?

Comment: ADyson may well be right, but anyway see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This isn't design flaw. The structure is pretty neat and yes I know how to handle through a single column but there were a lot of things that forced me to make separate tables.

Comment: ok well I'll take your word for it, I imagine there's some complexity involved. On another point, what do you need the left join for? You're not using columns from those tables in the query, and a left join doesn't restrict the result set.